# Как присовокупить к переменной данные по ссылке (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

Имеется код, в котором переменным был присвоен шифр base64.

Поступила задача: переиграть тему на систему "изображения по линку". Т.е. изображения будут залиты на сервак. Подскажите, как лучше присовокупить URL изображений к переменным, чтобы минимально калечить код.

```
var disease = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQ...AQ ';
```

Comment: `var desease = '/some/path/to/image.png'`  так что ли? или о чем вы?

Comment: Наверное. Мне не доводилось ранее работать с линками из JS (только в CSS и HTML с ними работал). Вот и интересуюсь, как это реализуется.

Comment: суть не в js, а в том, что значение указанной выше переменной вероятно подставляется в атрибут `src` какому-то `<img>`. Значением атрибута, как наверное, вам известно, может быть либо обычный URL изображения, либо  data-URL как у вас.

Comment: Ну значит смело ставлю линк. Из-за бейс64 такой дикий тормоз в девтулз.